# Is there a way to access HealthKit data through a web interface?

Tags: ios, health-kit

I would like to read, and ideally write to, my HealthKit data from a computer's web browser. Is this possible? I have not found any tools so far that let me do it.

An out of the box tool is ideal, but a script-based workaround that syncs with Google Spreadsheets or Dropbox would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any out-of-the-box solutions, but I'm looking for something similar, and posted [this related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167671/view-ios-health-data-externally).

Options:

- export data as XML files and email them to yourself
- use iTunes backup, 3rd party backup reader, get sqlite3 Databases

Either of these two can be fed into a PHP/RoR/JSP/.NET etc.. web app but so far there's no way to do it without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Because health data is so sensitive and protected by multiple laws, providing a web interface that can be arbitrary accessed by a web script from a web page the user browses to presents far to high of a risk to customer’s protected health information (PHI).

By only providing native Objective C / Swift interfaces to Health Kit, the manditory use of app signing and “entitlements”, in conjunction with the app vetting process that precedes availability in the App Store; Apple does its best to guarantee no bad web actors (malicious script kiddies) have a remote way to hack or socially engineer Health data from the user.